# following siblings in /w:tr in xdoc xml where the first contains specific text

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, docx, siblings

The XML file data is below. MS adds a ton of stuff for formating. I just want to give a clear idea of what I'm working with.

Traversing the data below is causing issues and is taking way to long to figure out.

```
`
<w:tbl>
<w:tblPr>
<w:tblStyle w:val="TableGrid"/>
<w:tblpPr w:leftFromText="180" w:rightFromText="180" w:vertAnchor="page" w:horzAnchor="margin" w:tblpY="2512"/>
<w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/>
<w:tblBorders>
<w:top w:val="none" w:sz="0" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
<w:left w:val="none" w:sz="0" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
<w:bottom w:val="none" w:sz="0" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
<w:right w:val="none" w:sz="0" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
<w:insideV w:val="none" w:sz="0" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
</w:tblBorders>
<w:tblLook w:val="04A0" w:firstRow="1" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:noHBand="0" w:noVBand="1"/>
</w:tblPr>
<w:tblGrid>
<w:gridCol w:w="5095"/>
<w:gridCol w:w="2435"/>
<w:gridCol w:w="1784"/>
</w:tblGrid>
```

Here is a table row within the table node.

```
<w:tr w:rsidR="00223B3F" w14:paraId="01B6D8D8" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidTr="00223B3F">
<w:trPr>
<w:trHeight w:val="582"/>
</w:trPr>
<w:tc>
<w:tcPr>
    <w:tcW w:w="5095" w:type="dxa"/>
    <w:tcBorders>
    <w:top w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    <w:bottom w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="7F7F7F" w:themeColor="text1" w:themeTint="80"/>
    <w:right w:val="single" w:sz="6" w:space="0" w:color="7F7F7F" w:themeColor="text1" w:themeTint="80"/>
    </w:tcBorders>
    <w:vAlign w:val="center"/>
</w:tcPr>
<w:p w14:paraId="10D9A4F1" w14:textId="655EE555" w:rsidR="00223B3F" w:rsidRPr="000B6F58" w:rsidRDefault="00223B3F" w:rsidP="00223B3F">
    <w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
    </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="00530DBC">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:b/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Job Title:</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:b/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve"> </w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:ins w:id="0" w:author="Joe Bloe" w:date="2019-09-09T11:06:00Z">
    <w:r w:rsidR="004A329B">
        <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:b/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Job Title Goes Here</w:t>
    </w:r>
    </w:ins>
</w:p>
</w:tc>
<w:tc>
<w:tcPr>
    <w:tcW w:w="4219" w:type="dxa"/>
    <w:gridSpan w:val="2"/>
    <w:tcBorders>
    <w:top w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="6" w:space="0" w:color="7F7F7F" w:themeColor="text1" w:themeTint="80"/>
    <w:bottom w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="7F7F7F" w:themeColor="text1" w:themeTint="80"/>
    <w:right w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    </w:tcBorders>
    <w:vAlign w:val="center"/>
</w:tcPr>
<w:p w14:paraId="089971FE" w14:textId="3FC87B7C" w:rsidR="00223B3F" w:rsidRPr="000B6F58" w:rsidRDefault="00223B3F" w:rsidP="00223B3F">
    <w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
    </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="00530DBC">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:b/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">Revision: </w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:ins w:id="1" w:author="Joe Bloe" w:date="2019-09-09T11:06:00Z">
    <w:r w:rsidR="004A329B">
        <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:b/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>10</w:t>
    </w:r>
    </w:ins>
</w:p>
</w:tc>
</w:tr>

<w:tr w:rsidR="00223B3F" w14:paraId="1330F531" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidTr="00223B3F">
<w:trPr>
<w:trHeight w:val="3383"/>
</w:trPr>
<w:tc>
<w:tcPr>
    <w:tcW w:w="9314" w:type="dxa"/>
    <w:gridSpan w:val="3"/>
    <w:tcBorders>
    <w:top w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    <w:bottom w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    <w:right w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    </w:tcBorders>
</w:tcPr>
<w:p w14:paraId="354EA9ED" w14:textId="323A59F1" w:rsidR="00223B3F" w:rsidDel="009D3E5D" w:rsidRDefault="000C2C7C" w:rsidP="00223B3F">
    <w:pPr>
    <w:spacing w:before="240"/>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:del w:id="3" w:author="Joe Bloe" w:date="2019-09-09T10:25:00Z"/>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
    </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:ins w:id="4" w:author="Joe Bloe" w:date="2019-09-09T10:25:00Z">
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Job summary Text</w:t>
    </w:r>
    </w:ins>
</w:p>
<w:p w14:paraId="25D9C722" w14:textId="3109C4D6" w:rsidR="00223B3F" w:rsidRPr="004401B9" w:rsidDel="009D3E5D" w:rsidRDefault="00223B3F" w:rsidP="00223B3F">
    <w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:del w:id="5" w:author="Joe Bloe" w:date="2019-09-09T10:25:00Z"/>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
    </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:del w:id="6" w:author="Joe Bloe" w:date="2019-09-09T10:25:00Z">
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="004401B9" w:rsidDel="009D3E5D">
        <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:delText>The is expected to encourage safe practices and enforce safety policies.</w:delText>
    </w:r>
    </w:del>
</w:p>
<w:p w14:paraId="2EB93B9E" w14:textId="309E9E7B" w:rsidR="00223B3F" w:rsidRPr="00E7046D" w:rsidRDefault="00223B3F" w:rsidP="00223B3F">
    <w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
    </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
</w:p>
</w:tc>
</w:tr>

<w:tr w:rsidR="00223B3F" w14:paraId="6DBA214C" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidTr="00223B3F">
<w:trPr>
<w:trHeight w:val="860"/>
</w:trPr>
<w:tc>
<w:tcPr>
    <w:tcW w:w="9314" w:type="dxa"/>
    <w:gridSpan w:val="3"/>
    <w:tcBorders>
    <w:top w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    <w:bottom w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    <w:right w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    </w:tcBorders>
    <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="auto"/>
    <w:vAlign w:val="center"/>
</w:tcPr>
<w:p w14:paraId="583B15A4" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00223B3F" w:rsidRPr="00B22FC4" w:rsidRDefault="00223B3F" w:rsidP="00223B3F">
    <w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
    </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r w:rsidRPr="00AD57B3">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:b/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Essenti</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:b/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">al Duties and Responsibilities – </w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Provide up to ten duties/responsibilities for this job, and the percentage of time spent doing each.   A minimum of two is required.</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
</w:tc>
</w:tr>

<w:tr w:rsidR="00223B3F" w14:paraId="7B68CE86" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidTr="00223B3F">
<w:trPr>
<w:trHeight w:val="432"/>
</w:trPr>
<w:tc>
<w:tcPr>
    <w:tcW w:w="7530" w:type="dxa"/>
    <w:gridSpan w:val="2"/>
    <w:tcBorders>
    <w:top w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    <w:bottom w:val="nil"/>
    <w:right w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    </w:tcBorders>
    <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="auto"/>
    <w:vAlign w:val="center"/>
</w:tcPr>
<w:p w14:paraId="189C4FF5" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00223B3F" w:rsidRPr="00985A63" w:rsidRDefault="00223B3F" w:rsidP="00223B3F">
    <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph"/>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:b/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
    </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
</w:p>
</w:tc>
<w:tc>
<w:tcPr>
    <w:tcW w:w="1784" w:type="dxa"/>
    <w:tcBorders>
    <w:top w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    <w:bottom w:val="nil"/>
    <w:right w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    </w:tcBorders>
    <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="auto"/>
    <w:vAlign w:val="center"/>
</w:tcPr>
<w:p w14:paraId="3FB41A7C" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00223B3F" w:rsidRPr="00985A63" w:rsidRDefault="00223B3F" w:rsidP="00223B3F">
    <w:pPr>
    <w:ind w:right="360"/>
    <w:jc w:val="right"/>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:b/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
    </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
</w:p>
</w:tc>
</w:tr>

<w:tr w:rsidR="00223B3F" w14:paraId="05FE164E" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidTr="00223B3F">
<w:trPr>
<w:trHeight w:val="432"/>
</w:trPr>
<w:tc>
<w:tcPr>
    <w:tcW w:w="7530" w:type="dxa"/>
    <w:gridSpan w:val="2"/>
    <w:tcBorders>
    <w:top w:val="nil"/>
    <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    <w:bottom w:val="nil"/>
    <w:right w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    </w:tcBorders>
    <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="auto"/>
</w:tcPr>
<w:p w14:paraId="7EC7F5D1" w14:textId="581F1E77" w:rsidR="00223B3F" w:rsidRPr="0091752E" w:rsidRDefault="009D3E5D" w:rsidP="0091752E">
    <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph"/>
    <w:numPr>
        <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
        <w:numId w:val="7"/>
    </w:numPr>
    <w:spacing w:after="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
    </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:ins w:id="7" w:author="Joe Bloe" w:date="2019-09-09T10:25:00Z">
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Duty 1</w:t>
    </w:r>
    </w:ins>
    <w:ins w:id="8" w:author="Joe Bloe" w:date="2019-09-09T15:24:00Z">
    <w:r w:rsidR="00E50AD7">
        <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>0 percent</w:t>
    </w:r>
    </w:ins>
</w:p>
</w:tc>
<w:tc>
<w:tcPr>
    <w:tcW w:w="1784" w:type="dxa"/>
    <w:tcBorders>
    <w:top w:val="nil"/>
    <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    <w:bottom w:val="nil"/>
    <w:right w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    </w:tcBorders>
    <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="auto"/>
</w:tcPr>
<w:p w14:paraId="582E5EF7" w14:textId="45477371" w:rsidR="00223B3F" w:rsidRPr="00985A63" w:rsidRDefault="009D3E5D" w:rsidP="00223B3F">
    <w:pPr>
    <w:ind w:right="360"/>
    <w:jc w:val="right"/>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:b/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
    </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:ins w:id="9" w:author="Joe Bloe" w:date="2019-09-09T10:26:00Z">
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:b/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>10</w:t>
    </w:r>
    </w:ins>
    <w:r w:rsidR="00223B3F" w:rsidRPr="00985A63">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:b/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>%</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
</w:tc>
</w:tr>

<w:tr w:rsidR="00223B3F" w14:paraId="68C9B037" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidTr="00223B3F">
<w:trPr>
<w:trHeight w:val="432"/>
</w:trPr>
<w:tc>
<w:tcPr>
    <w:tcW w:w="7530" w:type="dxa"/>
    <w:gridSpan w:val="2"/>
    <w:tcBorders>
    <w:top w:val="nil"/>
    <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    <w:bottom w:val="nil"/>
    <w:right w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    </w:tcBorders>
    <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="auto"/>
</w:tcPr>
<w:p w14:paraId="7FAA6960" w14:textId="0C06A70D" w:rsidR="00223B3F" w:rsidRPr="0091752E" w:rsidRDefault="009D3E5D" w:rsidP="0091752E">
    <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph"/>
    <w:numPr>
        <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
        <w:numId w:val="7"/>
    </w:numPr>
    <w:spacing w:after="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
    </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:ins w:id="10" w:author="Joe Bloe" w:date="2019-09-09T10:26:00Z">
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Duty 2</w:t>
    </w:r>
    </w:ins>
    <w:ins w:id="11" w:author="Joe Bloe" w:date="2019-09-09T15:24:00Z">
    <w:r w:rsidR="00E50AD7">
        <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>0 percent</w:t>
    </w:r>
    </w:ins>
</w:p>
</w:tc>
<w:tc>
<w:tcPr>
    <w:tcW w:w="1784" w:type="dxa"/>
    <w:tcBorders>
    <w:top w:val="nil"/>
    <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    <w:bottom w:val="nil"/>
    <w:right w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    </w:tcBorders>
    <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="auto"/>
</w:tcPr>
<w:p w14:paraId="47998D2C" w14:textId="36D49BCC" w:rsidR="00223B3F" w:rsidRPr="00985A63" w:rsidRDefault="00223B3F" w:rsidP="00E50AD7">
    <w:pPr>
    <w:ind w:right="360"/>
    <w:jc w:val="right"/>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:b/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:pPrChange w:id="12" w:author="Joe Bloe" w:date="2019-09-09T15:24:00Z">
        <w:pPr>
        <w:framePr w:hSpace="180" w:wrap="around" w:vAnchor="page" w:hAnchor="margin" w:y="2512"/>
        <w:ind w:right="360"/>
        <w:jc w:val="right"/>
        </w:pPr>
    </w:pPrChange>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:del w:id="13" w:author="Joe Bloe" w:date="2019-09-09T10:26:00Z">
    <w:r w:rsidDel="009D3E5D">
        <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:b/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:delText>%</w:delText>
    </w:r>
    </w:del>
    <w:ins w:id="14" w:author="Joe Bloe" w:date="2019-09-09T15:24:00Z">
    <w:r w:rsidR="00E50AD7">
        <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:b/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>2</w:t>
    </w:r>
    </w:ins>
    <w:ins w:id="15" w:author="Joe Bloe" w:date="2019-09-09T10:26:00Z">
    <w:r w:rsidR="009D3E5D">
        <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:b/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>0%</w:t>
    </w:r>
    </w:ins>
</w:p>
</w:tc>
</w:tr>

<w:tr w:rsidR="00223B3F" w14:paraId="0CF1F853" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidTr="00223B3F">
<w:trPr>
<w:trHeight w:val="432"/>
</w:trPr>
<w:tc>
<w:tcPr>
    <w:tcW w:w="7530" w:type="dxa"/>
    <w:gridSpan w:val="2"/>
    <w:tcBorders>
    <w:top w:val="nil"/>
    <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    <w:bottom w:val="nil"/>
    <w:right w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    </w:tcBorders>
    <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="auto"/>
</w:tcPr>
<w:p w14:paraId="1C7A2904" w14:textId="64B4FBA4" w:rsidR="00223B3F" w:rsidRPr="0091752E" w:rsidRDefault="009D3E5D" w:rsidP="0091752E">
    <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph"/>
    <w:numPr>
        <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
        <w:numId w:val="7"/>
    </w:numPr>
    <w:spacing w:after="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
    </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:ins w:id="16" w:author="Joe Bloe" w:date="2019-09-09T10:26:00Z">
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Duty 3</w:t>
    </w:r>
    </w:ins>
    <w:ins w:id="17" w:author="Joe Bloe" w:date="2019-09-09T15:24:00Z">
    <w:r w:rsidR="00E50AD7">
        <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve"> percent</w:t>
    </w:r>
    </w:ins>
</w:p>
</w:tc>
<w:tc>
<w:tcPr>
    <w:tcW w:w="1784" w:type="dxa"/>
    <w:tcBorders>
    <w:top w:val="nil"/>
    <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    <w:bottom w:val="nil"/>
    <w:right w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    </w:tcBorders>
    <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="auto"/>
</w:tcPr>
<w:p w14:paraId="15843BAC" w14:textId="44E2F591" w:rsidR="00223B3F" w:rsidRPr="00985A63" w:rsidRDefault="00E50AD7" w:rsidP="00223B3F">
    <w:pPr>
    <w:ind w:right="360"/>
    <w:jc w:val="right"/>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:b/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
    </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:ins w:id="18" w:author="Joe Bloe" w:date="2019-09-09T15:24:00Z">
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:b/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>3</w:t>
    </w:r>
    </w:ins>
    <w:r w:rsidR="00223B3F">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:b/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>%</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
</w:tc>
</w:tr>

<w:tr w:rsidR="00223B3F" w14:paraId="43C531F9" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidTr="00223B3F">
<w:trPr>
<w:trHeight w:val="432"/>
</w:trPr>
<w:tc>
<w:tcPr>
    <w:tcW w:w="7530" w:type="dxa"/>
    <w:gridSpan w:val="2"/>
    <w:tcBorders>
    <w:top w:val="nil"/>
    <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    <w:bottom w:val="nil"/>
    <w:right w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    </w:tcBorders>
    <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="auto"/>
</w:tcPr>
<w:p w14:paraId="39D03C87" w14:textId="15F7AA96" w:rsidR="00223B3F" w:rsidRPr="0091752E" w:rsidRDefault="009D3E5D">
    <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph"/>
    <w:numPr>
        <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
        <w:numId w:val="7"/>
    </w:numPr>
    <w:spacing w:after="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:pPrChange w:id="19" w:author="Joe Bloe" w:date="2019-09-09T10:27:00Z">
        <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph"/>
        <w:framePr w:hSpace="180" w:wrap="around" w:vAnchor="page" w:hAnchor="margin" w:y="2512"/>
        <w:numPr>
            <w:numId w:val="7"/>
        </w:numPr>
        <w:spacing w:after="0" w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
        <w:ind w:left="1080" w:hanging="360"/>
        </w:pPr>
    </w:pPrChange>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:ins w:id="20" w:author="Joe Bloe" w:date="2019-09-09T10:27:00Z">
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Duty 4</w:t>
    </w:r>
    </w:ins>
    <w:ins w:id="21" w:author="Joe Bloe" w:date="2019-09-09T15:24:00Z">
    <w:r w:rsidR="00E50AD7">
        <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>4 percent</w:t>
    </w:r>
    </w:ins>
</w:p>
</w:tc>
<w:tc>
<w:tcPr>
    <w:tcW w:w="1784" w:type="dxa"/>
    <w:tcBorders>
    <w:top w:val="nil"/>
    <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="4" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    <w:bottom w:val="nil"/>
    <w:right w:val="single" w:sz="18" w:space="0" w:color="auto"/>
    </w:tcBorders>
    <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="auto"/>
</w:tcPr>
<w:p w14:paraId="04AEDF9D" w14:textId="58D98A50" w:rsidR="00223B3F" w:rsidRPr="00985A63" w:rsidRDefault="00E50AD7" w:rsidP="00223B3F">
    <w:pPr>
    <w:ind w:right="360"/>
    <w:jc w:val="right"/>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:b/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
    </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:ins w:id="22" w:author="Joe Bloe" w:date="2019-09-09T15:25:00Z">
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:b/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>44</w:t>
    </w:r>
    </w:ins>
    <w:r w:rsidR="00223B3F">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
        <w:b/>
        <w:sz w:val="20"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>%</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
</w:tc>
</w:tr>     
</w:tbl>
`
```

Also the Duties table has mutlipe columns and I need to pull each colum seperatly. I do not have control over what is entered in the columns, otherwise I would just search for each row specifically.

Comment: I am using InnerText from the </w:tr> elements because it puts all the text that was broken up into one string.

Comment: How large is the file?  How many nest level do you have?  What is the extension of the xml file (type of xml)?  The fastest method is usually xml linq which usually with a large file will take a couple of seconds.  I like parsing file once and creating dictionaries to make loop up quick.  With xml linq you can only parse what you need easily.  Using serialization everything gets parsed and can take longer than linq.

Comment: It is actually a .docx file which contains .XML files. The file is not that large, It is only a two or three-page word doc. The problem is just pulling the siblings below a specific node. Those nodes are free -text so there is nothing to search on. I just need the siblings below the row I can search on. I have not tried Linq yet. Speed is not the issue since the file is so small anyway.

The data/text being extracted is being inserted into an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: You can use the XDocument.Parse(string) to create a document.  Do you need all the data parsed or just certain fields?

Comment: Just all the siblings following a specific row. The specific row does contain text that should not change. 
1) search for row containing 'text' 
2) loop through all the following siblings and extract the text from each. 
    The text in the following rows is free text.
Also the rows from the searched row and all the following rows has two columns and I need to seperate them to new fields.

the real problem is just locating the first row and then all the following siblings. It should be strait forward and easy bit I'm no seeing something obvious I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

See if following gives you what you need :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication131
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants()
                .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "p")
                .SelectMany(x => x.Descendants().Where(y => y.Name.LocalName == "t")
                    .Select(z => new
                    {
                        paraId = (string)x.Attributes().Where(y => y.Name.LocalName == "paraId").FirstOrDefault(),
                        text = (string)z
                    })).ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

---

The following merges the text in same paragraph number :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication131
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants()
                .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "p")
                .Select(x => x.Descendants().Where(y => y.Name.LocalName == "t")
                    .Select(z => new
                    {
                        paraId = (string)x.Attributes().Where(y => y.Name.LocalName == "paraId").FirstOrDefault(),
                        text = (string)z
                    })
                    ).Where(y => y.Count() > 0).Select(y => new { paraId = y.First().paraId, text = string.Join("", y.Select(z => z.text))})
                    .ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using 'following-sibling::w:tr worked. We had to offset it due to a blank line but otherwise, it solved the problem. The selectNodes call below returned all the nodes following the one selected. I then was able to loop through the nodes returned and retrieve the data needed.

XmlNodeList essentialDutiesList = xdoc.SelectNodes("//w:tr/*[contains(., 'Essential Duties and Responsibilities')]/../following-sibling::w:tr[position() > 1]", nsManager);